# Drawing with Tikz (Physical System)

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, technical-drawing

I want to draw the following in Tikz (Tikz is the way to go here right?)
[image: System]

As I am new to Tikz, I tried do draw it by hand to see if someone here can help me.
[image: Drawing]

If possible, it would be nice for it to have the dimensions of the parts of the system too.

Thanks a lot.

EDIT:
I did this until now: (Inspired by Marco comment here [Simple Ramp Diagram with Ball](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290491/simple-ramp-diagram-with-ball))

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.25]

%\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (25,15);

\draw [fill=gray, gray] (0,0) rectangle (1,6); 
\draw [|<->|] (-0.8,0) -- (-0.8,6) node [midway,align=left,xshift=-0.2cm]{$h$};
\draw [fill=gray, gray] (0,5) rectangle (20,6);   
\draw [fill=gray, gray] (19,6) rectangle (20,0);
\draw [fill=gray, gray] (2,6) rectangle (3,12);
\draw [|<->|] (-0.8,6.1) -- (-0.8,11.9) node [midway,align=left,xshift=-0.25cm]{$H$};


\end{tikzpicture}
```

I'm struggling to make the angled retangle and the ball in the same style as the other retangles.

Any sugestion from a more experienced Tikz user would be welcome!

Comment: It would probably be very useful for you to go through the tutorials in the first part of the TikZ manual. That will likely tell you almost all you need to know to make that sketch. Then if any specific parts are troublesome, show the code you have so far, and ask about those.

Comment: (TikZ is the most traveled way around here, but there are several other ways leading to same destination. Probably each way has it own nice parts and pitfalls.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I read the Tikz manual, so I understand it a little bit. I even made some simpler drawings (can I post code in a comment?). This just is being too frustrating to me. Soo hard!

Comment: @GabrielRibeiro You cannot post a code sample in a comment, but you can append it to your question by editing it.

Comment: @GabrielRibeiro Not only you can post, you should post your code (in the question). This should run (even if the drawing is not the one you expect).

Comment: You might start with either of the answers to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290491/simple-ramp-diagram-with-ball).  (Especially mine with Metapost :-)

Comment: Or the one which isn't @Thruston 's if you've started to learn TikZ ;). You should be able to extend the code there to get at least most of what you want. It even has the dimensions added in.

Comment: @Thruston edited!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this I would start by placing (and naming) `nodes` or `coordinates` at the desired locations. (A `coordinate` is basically a `node` with no size and no caption.) In the example below I name them according to location, with l/r meaning left/right, and t/m/b meaning top/mid/bottom.

I would then connect the nodes as necessary. Using a thick line may be easier in this case than orienting a rectangle. See p. 38 of the [TikZ manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) for an explanation of `|-`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.25,inner sep=2pt,myball/.style={draw=black,line width=0.5pt,fill=red!50,circle,radius=2pt,above=1.5pt}]
\coordinate(bl) at (0,0);
\coordinate(ml) at (0,6);
\coordinate(tl) at (2,10);
\coordinate(mr) at (19,6);
\coordinate(br) at (19,0);
\coordinate(rampend) at (16,6);

\draw[line width=3pt,gray](bl)--(ml)--(mr)--(br)-- ++(5,0)
    node[near start,myball]{};
\draw[line width=3pt,gray](ml) (ml -| tl) -- (tl) -- (rampend)
    node[pos=0.05,myball]{};

\draw [|<->|] (bl)  ++(-0.75,0) node(leftlabel)[shape=coordinate]{} -- (ml -| leftlabel) node [midway,left]{$h$};
\draw [|<->|] (ml -| leftlabel) -- (tl -| leftlabel) node [midway,left]{$H$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This isn't much, but perhaps it will help you get started.

Comment: Nice, I learned a lot from your answer!
Thanks!